# How would I unmarshal JSON to a class in swift?

Tags: json, swift

How do I unmarshal JSON onto a swift class? Here is [Go code](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Unmarshal) which illustrates what I am after.

I can't find any reference which shows how to do this in Swift. A reference I looked at ( among others ) was this [tutorial](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/swiftyjson-how-to-handle-json-in-swift/111).

But those example uses dictionaries. I want to use objects.

I saw attempts around this la: http://bit.ly/1t3W2Gi

but that post does not unmarshal to a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays, you’d do this with `Codable` types and `JSONDecoder`.

```
struct Animal: Codable {
    let type: String
    let sound: String
    let legs: Int
}

let json = """
    [{"type": "dog", "sound": "woof", "legs": 4},
    {"type": "cat", "sound": "meow", "legs": 4},
    {"type": "snake", "sound": "hiss", "legs": 0}]
    """

let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let animals = try JSONDecoder().decode([Animal].self, from: data)
    print(animals)
} catch {
    print("json failed: \(error)")
}
```

For more information, see:

- [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)
- Using [JSON with Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types) sample code.

---

The above is for Swift 3 and later. See the [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26490922/2) of this a answer, predating `JSONDecoder` for earlier versions of Swift.

Answer (score 4):

We've written an open source, protocol-based Swift framework called [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) that you might want to consider. From the README:

> To support mapping, a class just needs to implement the MapperProtocol. ObjectMapper uses the "<=" operator to define how each member variable maps to and from JSON.

```
class User: MapperProtocol {

  var username: String?
  var age: Int?
  var weight: Double?
  var arr: [AnyObject]?
  var dict: [String : AnyObject] = [:]
  var friend: User?
  var birthday: NSDate?

  // MapperProtocol    
  class func map(mapper: Mapper, object: User) {
    object.username <= mapper["username"]
    object.age <= mapper["age"]
    object.weight <= mapper["weight"]
    object.arr <= mapper["arr"]
    object.dict <= mapper["dict"]
    object.friend <= mapper["friend"]
    object.birthday <= (mapper["birthday"], DateTransform<NSDate, Int>())
  }
}
```

While not as unobtrusive as, say, Gson for Java, it's fairly lightweight and explicit. Although it's in beta, we're happily using it internally.

Comment: I am using it and it is really great. But... I need to be able to send back to server even models which have as a property an array or dictionary with other mappable properties, but which are empty... so in the json this kind of properties would be displayed as for example: "images" : {}. If this arrays are int arrays or other simple types, then it is sent empty as it should, but if it is an array of another custom mappable type, it just does not include it in the final JSON if there are no items in it.

Comment: Can you file that as an issue on Github? We'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following link will be helpful for the usage of "Object Mapper"

```
[https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper][1]
```

Comment: You might have missed it, but Nathan's answer—which goes into more detail—already linked to this.